What is an efficient method to calculate multiple "offset-traces" in JAX?
Given a matrix m with shape (n, n), I need to compute the series of "offset traces" [np.trace(m, offset=i) for i in range(q)] in JAX. For my application, n >> q, and q is a static parameter.
The obvious JAX approach using vmap does not work, possibly because although the trace has fixed output size, each offset diagonal has a different length?
I came up with two other approaches using JAX which work but are about 100x slower than NumPy. get_traces_jax_1 is the more efficient of the two. But it does a lot of extra work when I only need a few diagonals, and I don't think that extra work gets compiled away.
Is there a more efficient way to do this in JAX with similar performance to NumPy? I want to use JAX because:

I need to vmap this across many matrices;
It is part of a larger algorithm, other parts of which are significantly sped up by JAX jit.

Below are the methods I explored and timings on my computer.
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import jax
jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True) # default is float32
from jax import numpy as jnp
from functools import partial

n, q = 1000, 5

# check the methods produce the same result
def distance(u, v):
    return jnp.max(jnp.abs(u - v))

# numpy - this is what I want
def get_traces_np(mat, q):
    return np.array([np.trace(mat, offset=i) for i in range(q)])

# jax
# !! This does not work
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def get_traces_jax_broken(mat, q):
    return jax.vmap(lambda i: jnp.trace(mat, offset=i))(jnp.arange(q)) # !! does not work

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def get_traces_jax_0(mat, q):
    return jnp.array([jnp.trace(mat, offset=i) for i in range(q)])

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def get_traces_jax_1(mat, q):
    n = mat.shape[0]
    padded = jnp.pad(mat, ((0, 0), (0, n-1)), 'constant')
    shifts = jax.vmap(lambda v, i: jnp.roll(v, -i))(padded, jnp.arange(n))[:, :n]
    return jnp.sum(shifts, axis=0)[:q]

mat = random.uniform(size=(n, n))
# Check they produce the same result and precompile
d0 = distance(get_traces_np(mat, q), get_traces_jax_0(mat, q))
d1 = distance(get_traces_np(mat, q), get_traces_jax_1(mat, q))
print(f'Errors: {d0}, {d1}')

mat = jnp.array(mat)
print('Numpy:')
%timeit get_traces_np(mat, q) # 7.43 microseconds
print('Jax 0:')
%timeit get_traces_jax_0(mat, q) # 4.82ms
print('Jax 1:')
%timeit get_traces_jax_1(mat, q) # 1.22ms


vmapping jnp.trace across offset doesn't work because as currently implemented, the offset parameter of jnp.trace must be static, and vmapped parameters are not static. You could address this by constructing your own version of the trace function that does not require a static parameter; for example:
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def dynamic_trace(x, offset):
  assert x.ndim == 2
  i = jnp.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None]
  j = jnp.arange(x.shape[1])
  return jnp.sum(jnp.where(i + offset == j, x, 0))

x = jnp.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

offset = jnp.arange(-2, 3)

jax.vmap(dynamic_trace, in_axes=(None, 0))(x, offset)
# Array([ 8, 13, 15, 18,  9], dtype=int32)

jnp.array([jnp.trace(x, int(o)) for o in offset])
# Array([ 8, 13, 15, 18,  9], dtype=int32)

In terms of benchmark comparisons, you should first make sure you're measuring what you think you're measuring. For example, your benchmark is written in such a way that it doesn't just measure runtime, but also device transfer and JIT compilation costs. It also ignores potentially confounding effects of asynchronous dispatch. For a discussion of these issues, see JAX FAQ: Benchmarking JAX code.
Even accounting for this, however, I would not expect JAX to be faster than NumPy here for the reasons discussed at JAX FAQ: Is JAX Faster than NumPy?. Namely, this benchmark is doing a short sequence of relatively small array operations on CPU: this is a regime in which NumPy will always beat JAX due to its lower per-operation dispatch overhead. But not to worry: when this operation is used as part of a larger JIT-compiled function, those dispatch costs are amortized away.

https://github.com/google/jax/pull/21227 will make jnp.trace work with dynamic offsets, so you'll be able to vmap it directly.
